# How do I convert a list/dictionary into a Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, dataframe

I have a JSON response (sample below) that I'm trying to convert into a DataFrame. I've had several issues with the data being listed as columns (1 x 346), etc. I only need the 5 columns listed below:

```
area_name,
date,
month,
unemployment_rate,
year
```

Here's my code:

```
edd_ca_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(edd_ca, orient="index", 
                                   columns=["area_name", "month", "date", "year", "unemployment_rate"])
```

and here's a sample of the JSON response:

```
[[{'area_name': 'California',
   'area_type': 'State',
   'date': '1990-01-01T00:00:00.000',
   'employment': '14099700',
   'labor_force': '14953900',
   'month': 'January',
   'seasonally_adjusted_y_n': 'N',
   'status_preliminary_final': 'Final',
   'unemployment': '854200',
   'unemployment_rate': '5.7',
   'year': '1990'},

 {'area_name': 'California',
   'area_type': 'State',
   'date': '1990-02-01T00:00:00.000',
   'employment': '14206700',
   'labor_force': '15049400',
   'month': 'February',
   'seasonally_adjusted_y_n': 'N',
   'status_preliminary_final': 'Final',
   'unemployment': '842800',
   'unemployment_rate': '5.6',
   'year': '1990'},
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you dont have a dict, you have a list!

Comment: I believe that the way to_dict works is that it expects all column values to be under the same entry, ie. `{state: ['CA', 'CA', 'CA'], month: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']}`. You may have to first reformat this, but someone may have a better answer.

Comment: @TeENeTe yes, but `to_dict()` doesn't actually care about that: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0409521665bd436a10aea7e06336066bf07ff057/pandas/core/frame.py#L905-L985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a list of dictionaries, this is as simple as passing all the data to a new `DataFrame` and specifying what columns you want to keep:

```
import pandas as pd

all_data = [{'area_name': 'California',
   'area_type': 'State',
   'date': '1990-01-01T00:00:00.000',
   'employment': '14099700',
   'labor_force': '14953900',
   'month': 'January',
   'seasonally_adjusted_y_n': 'N',
   'status_preliminary_final': 'Final',
   'unemployment': '854200',
   'unemployment_rate': '5.7',
   'year': '1990'},

 {'area_name': 'California',
   'area_type': 'State',
   'date': '1990-02-01T00:00:00.000',
   'employment': '14206700',
   'labor_force': '15049400',
   'month': 'February',
   'seasonally_adjusted_y_n': 'N',
   'status_preliminary_final': 'Final',
   'unemployment': '842800',
   'unemployment_rate': '5.6',
   'year': '1990'}]

keep_columns = ['area_name','date','month','unemployment_rate','year']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=keep_columns, data=all_data)

print(df)
```

Output

```
    area_name                     date     month unemployment_rate  year
0  California  1990-01-01T00:00:00.000   January               5.7  1990
1  California  1990-02-01T00:00:00.000  February               5.6  1990
```

Comment: Thank you @b-fg. That worked.I had a few options to try . . .

Comment: Ok, consider upvoting/accepting the answer if this was the simpler solution! thanks!